# PCA application and interpretration

Tags: pca

I want to apply principal component analysis (PCA) to get an index. There are 6 dimensions covering 21 indicators. I took the average of the indicators in each dimension and applied PCA on 6 dimensions. I also used the `Rotate` command. My questions are:

1. Should I apply PCA on each indicator separately, or is my procedure right?
2. Should the `Rotate` command be applied or not? If so, why is it good?